# Is it possible to have a production with one or more terminal(s) in the LHS of a recursively enumerable language?

Tags: grammar, automata, automata-theory, chomsky-hierarchy

As Recursively enumerable grammar is unrestricted, is it possible to have a production with one or more terminal(s) in the LHS (ie no non-terminals)?

Comment: Yes, but this fact does not change anythng.

Comment: actually, it does. it is good till context-sensitive grammar. I mean, it can be possible that a terminal has some impact on a non-terminal, that may reflect in the derived string. But, how can a non-terminal derive a string?

Comment: In an unrestricted grammar, a non-terminal does not derive a string; a string derives another string. The concepts "terminal" and "non-terminal" really are only meaningful for restricted grammars -- or, perhaps better said, although the terms can be defined, the meanings aren't particularly useful.

Comment: okay. thanks a lot, man.